# htaccess - disable subdomains except www

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I want to disable subdomains, except www, so this would not work anymore: **subdomain.mysite.tld**, but this would: **www.mysite.tld**

I also want to redirect from **mysite.tld** to **www.mysite.tld**, which I know how to do, but if have mysite.tld it won't redirect to www, instead it will throw a forbidden error...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mysite.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mysite.tld$
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule .? http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Those are two options I thinks, right? So Marian has to pick one.

Comment: @Gerben: Sorry I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: If the first RewriteRule matches the second one is never executed.

Comment: @Gerben: No, that's not correct. First rule executes when domain name is anything other than `mysite.tld` or `www.mysite.tld` and if true then it blocks that subdomain. In 2nd rule it simply checks whether a domain doesn't start with `www.` anf if true then it appends `www.` in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite to www:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.tld[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.tld/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Won't fix the subdomain problem. Rather use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.tld$ [NC]`

Comment: Yeah, should have mentioned that it wouldn't fix the subdomain problem...I wasn't sure how to do that, thanks!